Better understanding accels/nemo file syntax to add keyboard shortcuts for custom Nemo scripts
I carefully followed the instructions to add keyboard shortcuts to custom Nemo scripts as explained in this Ask Ubuntu answer and this Stack Overflow answer.
Although this technique works great to modify Nemo keyboard shortcuts, the instructions aren't working to add keyboard shortcuts to Nemo scripts on a Linux Mint Cinnamon 21.3 box.  To help debug this issue, I would like to better understand the syntax of the example line that implements this functionality (this line is contained in the accels/nemo file, which is located in a folder pointed to by environment variable GNOME22_USER_DIR):
(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ScriptsGroup/script_file:\\s\\s\\shome\\sUSERNAME\\s.local\\sshare\\snemo\\sscripts\\sedit.sh" "F4")

Why are backslashes used instead of forward slashes?
Why is the use of \s needed?
Just to make sure, is \\s\\s\\s after /script_file: correct?


Edit: Shortly after posting this, I resolved the larger issue, but I'm still interested in learning the answers to the above questions.

If each \\s is equivalent to a /, then that looks like file:///home/... which is a reasonable instance of a file:// URI. No idea about anything else here, however.

@muru Thanks.  What is defining that \\s is equivalent to /?  Which spec is that?
